# Transferring data across activities

Tags: android

I have a GCM class, which gets a message that has 2 separate strings from Google GCM server. I need to use those 2 strings inside another activity of my application. The problem is that i do not know in advance how many these gcm messages are gonna be. I need to store these values and use them in another Activity to present them to the user inside a layout. I' m finding this difficult cause  first of all, i don't know how many these messages are gonna be, so i can't draw the layout in advance, and secondly cause i haven't found an effective of storing these 2 strings together, so that i am able later to manipulate them.

Each group of these two strings, belong to a user and should be stored in a way so that they can be retrieved separately from other group of strings.

I have tried to do this by using SharePrefrences or intents but i can't find a proper solution to this.

I know my question might seem silly, and i am not asking for a solution, but i am stuck and i would be really glad, if someone could give me some advice or guidance on some workaround to this, or where to look..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to store them in an `ArrayList` or `HashMap` and send them through an `Intent`. You won't need to know how many there are, just use a loop to add however many exist into the list. When showing them, you can use a `ListView` to show them so you don't have to worry about knowing how many there are each time but you can get the count so you can know if needed. Other than that, its hard to say without seeing what you have tried, what is/isn't working/ or what you already know so I have added a few links which may be helpful in understanding these objects

[ArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html)

[HashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html)

consider [LinkedHashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) if you are concerned with the order of the data.

Comment: How will this loop be working if i don't know how many the messages are? You mean i should use try{}? I thought that by using HashMap the number of items added must be fixed..

Comment: I guess you probably wouldn't need a loop, its hard for me to "see" without seeing some visual (code or otherwise) but I just meant to add whatever messages you have to either type of list, however you need to do that. I have never known of the # of items needing to be fixed. You can do this dynamically

Comment: If i may be more specific, the incoming message, regarding each user, is a separate message for each user, so i can't just extract all the messages from a json object for example..